# How to display the asian language in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, southeast-asian-languages

I stored a geojson file (around 150 polygons) on Geoserver and called this layer with the WFS in OpenLayers (v4.6.4).

When the users clicks on the map, I display the information of the polygons. Nevertheless, It's a project for Asia and I have to manage special letter.

Do you know if there is a library to manage the asian letter with OpenLayers?

I'm using the function FeatureInfo of the WFS layer and not the file stored in my database postgresql.

Comment: Remove *thank for help* and improve format

Comment: OpenLayers should be able to display anything which the browser can display, although right to left languages such as Arabic might not format correctly. If you are unable to read special characters from the server response try adding `&format_options=CHARSET:UTF-8` to the WFS url